# PowerShell List considers [ and ] in Count

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I have list like this `["a", "b"]` which is a result of an API. When I check the Count, it is **4 (not 2)** because it is including [and].

Is there any way to handle this? I want only 2 as count

Comment: `["a", "b"]` is not valid PowerShell syntax, whatever it is, it is not a PowerShell list. You will need to provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like Json to me so the simple solution would be to convert it to a Powershell object, like so:

```
(ConvertFrom-Json '["a", "b"]').Count
```